# link error libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib, but I have boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have a link error in VS.
It can't find `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib`.
But I have `boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib`.
Why the VS always want to find `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib`?

And I added `boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib` in linker->input.

Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The libboost* are the static libraries. Use BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK to link to dynamic libraries. see [Building Boost libraries for Visual Studio](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11597/Building-Boost-libraries-for-Visual-Studio)